# Google Sheets Script - Copy and Clear

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

i've done the following code

```
function datenbankSpeichern() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("WTFCars");

  var source = sheet.getRange("B5:P5");

  sheet.insertRowAfter(38);

  source.copyTo(sheet.getRange("B39"), {contentsOnly:true});
}
```

Now what I need is, I want to reset the content of B5,C5 and E5. B5 and C5 are just text columns and E5 is a date value. How I can reset them to empty values without deleting the date column? Means when I double click that I still get a calendar as selection but there is no more date in there.

Here some screenshots for explanation : 
https://prnt.sc/sg03i9 before copy

and how it should looks like after copy

https://prnt.sc/sg04qh

Everything need to be in one script.
Would be nice if someone could help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below your last line, add

```
["B5", "C5", "E5"].forEach (function (r) {sheet.getRange(r).clearContent()})
```

and see if that helps?